# How to redirect url based on only one part of the path?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Let me explain what I mean:

I want to redirect from https://example.net/category/83745/my-first-post to https://myredirect.net/my-first-post but without considering /category/numbers/

For the moment I work with this:

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/category/83745/my-first-post')
{
    window.location.href="https://myredirect.net/my-first-post";
}
```

And it is working fine but as I described I need to remove /category/numbers/ because they could be different and only consider this part **/my-first-post** for the redirection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you can do this on the server using `.htaccess` rewrite rules (that way the browser's address bar will still show the long URL though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String's methods [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
window.location.href = "https://myredirect.net" + path.slice(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just ignore the first 2 parts dynamically and only care about the last part of the URL then just do the following:

```
var stringContains = function (str, partial){
    return (str.indexOf(partial) > -1);
};

var url = '/category/83745/my-first-post';


if(stringContains(url, "/category")){
   var parts = a.split("/");
   window.location.href = parts[parts.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a regular expression match on the pathname

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/my-first-post$/)) {
    window.location.href='/my-first-post';
}
```

More on regexes: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Another good tool for building and testing regexes: https://regex101.com/

Edit:

To give an example of how to regex according to the more fleshed out specs from Chris G

```
let pathmatch = window.location.pathname.match(/([^\/]+)$/g);
window.location.href = '/' + pathmatch[0];
```

Thus, regex can be utilized to grab any pattern and use it later.
IF there is a need to make sure the pathname contains category and/or numbers, it is easily added in to the pattern. This one simply disregards anything before the last forward slash (/)

Comment: If you're going to literally state the pathname, why do a `match()` in the first place...?

Comment: @chris-g what do you mean "literally state", thats a real regex, matching only when the path ends with specified string. The op specificly said "but without considering /category/numbers/" so i purposefully left that part out. You could put .* in front but to what end?

Comment: Not only that, because it is a match(), you can put captures in that can later be used in the redirect. It is an extensible solution to a basic problem

Comment: Yeah, I know how regex works. What I mean is that not every blogpost is going to be called `my-first-post` obviously, so your solution is useless for any other path that needs to be rewritten, see OP's last sentence where he specifically mentions that a solution needs to remove the category and number no matter what the title slug at the end is. See hindmost's answer for the only correct one (out of four answers).

Comment: A regex based solution is of course possible but it would require a regex like `/\/category\/\d+\/([A-Za-z-])$`

Comment: @chris-g Like so? A redirect to whatever the "title slug" is

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex. Something like

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/category\/\d+\/my\-first\-post$/)
{
    window.location.href="https://myredirect.net/my-first-post";
}
```